# How is System.out.println(4*2147483647) equal to -4 in java?

Tags: java

I am a Java beginner and pretty confused with this.

How is `System.out.println(4*2147483647)` equal to -4 in java?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It is due to integer silent overflow.

`2147483647 == Integer.MAX_VALUE` is the maximum value for an integer.

Silent overflow means that `2147483647 + 1 == Integer.MIN_VALUE = -2147483648`
You can then see that `2147483647 + 2147483647 == 2147483647 + (-2147483648 + - 1) == -2`

In other words, `2147483647 * 2 == -2`, and you can now see why `2147483647 * 4 == -4`.

More technically, the result is defined by the [Java Language Specification #15.17.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.1):

> If an integer multiplication overflows, then the result is the low-order bits of the mathematical product as represented in some sufficiently large two's-complement format. As a result, if overflow occurs, then the sign of the result may not be the same as the sign of the mathematical product of the two operand values.

Comment: I know what you are saying, but to a newbie it is not obvious. Better to explain it in steps.

Answer (score 13):

It has to do with the way processors perform a binary mutiplication. The number you have in there is the maximum signed integer, which is represented as **0111111111111111111111111** (I haven't checked the number of ones there, but I assume you get the idea).

When you mutiply by 4, is like doing a left shift by 2, which results in **11111111111111111111100** (which represents -4). You might want to read [how mutiplication is done in binary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_multiplier).

Answer (score 3):

Because the result is out of the range of an `int`.
[Primitive Data Types](http://www.cafeaulait.org/course/week2/02.html)

To solve this, use a `long` instead of an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using int (4 bytes) and not long (8 bytes)

```
System.out.println(4*2147483647);
```

Try adding an l (for lema) after one of the numbers so that the result is a long and not an Integer. Integer has a max value smaller than your result
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE

```
System.out.println(4l * 2147483647);
```

or

```
System.out.println(4 * 2147483647l);
```

The above two give the correct result. That is 8589934588

Answer (score 0):

Most integers in computer system based on 32-bit which means 4 byte (you can use 64bit  or much too). You can have maximum 4,294,967,295 in a 32bit integer. So 4,294,967,295 + 5 will cause overflow give you 5. Also -1 means 4,294,967,295 in integer. Because there is a negative bit.

**More Info:**
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_(computer_science)

Comment: Your example uses unsigned int. There are no unsigned int in Java.

Comment: 4,294,967,295 is the maximum value of integer, which is 0xFFFFFFFF in hexadecimal. So if you give + 5 to the value, you will get a positive value. No matter its normal or unsigned, you will get positive. If its signed you will get negative value no matter what is stored on int.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of how a computer stores numbers in memory.
2147483647 * 4 = 8589934588

8589934588 in binary results in 1 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1100

The first one is a bit which signifies the number it preceeds is negative.

The next part can be explained with two's complement.

Two's complement is a way to represent negative values which in calculated by invering all bits, then adding one.
This will result in  0011 (the inversion of the last 4 bytes) then adding one causes it to be 0100 which is the binary representation of 4.

Because the sign bit is on negative, it results in -4