# Why 2*Integer.MAX_VALUE = -2?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does Java handle integer underflows and overflows and how would you check for it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001836/how-does-java-handle-integer-underflows-and-overflows-and-how-would-you-check-fo)
>   [How is System.out.println(4*2147483647) equal to -4 in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11795522/how-is-system-out-println42147483647-equal-to-4-in-java)

I want to know why this holds:

```
2 * Integer.MAX_VALUE == -2
```

I'm look forward to your response.

Comment: [Integer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow).

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001836/how-does-java-handle-integer-underflows-and-overflows-and-how-would-you-check-fo

Comment: Lots of downvotes. Is this a particularly bad question? Fixed integer arithmetic is odd (and should be obscure).

Comment: I haven't down voted but I would assume its because its a quite often asked question (several answers on stack overflow) and the question probably lacks any research.

Comment: @Scorpion Best to close as duplicate rather than downvoting. I haven't seen it (only looking at the Java tag, which may explain it).

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline I agree and that's why no down votes from me.

Answer (score 6):

You get this result because of an [integer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow): in a [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) system of representing negative integers, taking the max value which is `011.....11`<sub>2</sub> and multiplying it by `2` gives you `11.....110`<sub>2</sub>, which corresponds to `-2`.

Answer (score 1):

That is because of the Integer overflow.

Answer (score 1):

`Integer.MAX_VALUE` is `0x7FFFFFFF`.  Multiply by two and you get `0xFFFFFFFE` (equivalent to shifting left one bit).  This is a negative number (the first bit is 1) and is the binary representation of `-2`.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of two's complement, where the lef most bit is used to signify if a number is positive (0) or negative (1). So when you add max int by itself (equivalent of multiplfy by two), this happens:

```
  011111111111111111111111
+ 011111111111111111111111
__________________________
  111111111111111111111110
```

and `111111111111111111111110` represents -2.

Answer (score 0):

The MAX_VALUE of Int is 2^31 - 1  = 2147483647 = 0111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111(binary number) the highest bit (here is the first bit 0, indicates the integer is   a positive number, when 1 indicates negative.

(suppose the length of an integer is 4bytes), 2 * MAX_VALUE,in computer an integer by 2 times is left shift(operator << ) on bits, eg. 2 << 1 = 4; 2 << 2 = 8; so 0111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 << 1 become 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1110 which is equal to -2 in decimal.